# How to return all related Opportunities, Cases, Contacts from an accountid in one single return statement

Tags: apex, javascript, controller

there is a method for returning list of Opportunities, Contacts, Cases based on Accountid. Javascript method has to receive those lists and display in popup.
How can we return list of contacts, cases, opportunities at a time and how we access those lists in javascript. Please suggest me a solution.
sample code is like below :

```
List<Contact> lisOfContacts = [select id, name, 
                                              (select id from Opportunities),
                                              (select id from Cases)
                                              from Contact where id=:myId];  

for(Contact acc:lisOfContacts){
    for(Opportunity opp:acc.Opportunities){
        oopList.add(opp);           
    }
    for(Case caseList: acc.Cases){
        casList.add(caseList);  

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an Apex Wrapper class to hold all of the data for one account.  In the example below I modified your example query a bit; your question asked about getting data for an `Account`, but your example queried `Contacts`.  I've built the query around `Account`, but the method stands even if you need to modify things a bit.

Also, to maximize flexibility (and to demonstrate the technique), I built the initial method (`fetchAccounts`) to get info on a *list* of `Account`s; I then have a `fetchAccount`) method which returns a single `Account` by calling `fetchAccounts`.  If you know you will never need a list of `Account`s you can eliminate this.

Finally, you didn't say if the javascript that will access this data is part of a Lightning component; in case it is I added the `@AuraEnabled` flag to the wrapper class and its properties to ensure it would work with Lightning.

```
public List<AccountResult> fetchAccounts(Set<id> accountIds) {
  List<AccountResult> results = new List<AccountResult>();
  for (AccountResult acct : [
      select id, name, 
             (select id from Cases),
             (select id from Contacts),
             (select id from Opportunities),
        from Contact
       where id=:myId
  ]) {
    results.add(new AccountResult(acct));
  }
  return results;
}

public AccountResult fetchAccount(Id accountId) {
  List<AccountResult> results = fetchAccounts(new Set<Id>{ accountId });
  if (results.size() == 0) return null;
  return results[0];
}

@AuraEnabled
class AccountResult {
  @AuraEnabled public Id id {get; set;}
  @AuraEnabled public String name {get; set;}
  @AuraEnabled public List<Case> cases {get; set;}
  @AuraEnabled public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}
  @AuraEnabled public List<Opportunity> opportunities {get; set;}

  public AccountResult(Account a) {
    this.id = a.id;
    this.name = a.name;
    this.cases = a.cases;
    this.contacts = a.contacts;
    this.opportunities = a.opportunities
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use add a  wrapper class of contact opportunity and cases and return wrapper list

Comment: Can you provide an example of the class you are referencing, perhaps even based on the example code the OP has used?

Comment: Please try to give detailed answer with some code samples where necessary